# Python OpenGL not working properly when trying to color 3D objects

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I am getting started with PyOpenGL and when I tried coloring, it just gave me some fancy results

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
verticies = (
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (1, -1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, -1, 1)
)
edges=(
    (0,1),
    (0,5),
    (1,2),
    (1,6),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (0,3),
    (3,4),
    (4,7),
    (6,7),
    (5,6),
    (4,5)
)

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (0,1,6,5),
    (0,3,4,5),
    (3,2,7,4),
    (1,2,7,6),
    (4,5,6,7),
)

colors= (




)
def color_in_face(color, face_index):
    for vertex in surfaces[face_index]:
        glColor3fv(color)
        glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    color_in_face((1,0,0), 0)
    color_in_face((0,1,0), 1)
    color_in_face((0,0,1), 2)
    color_in_face((1,1,0), 3)
    color_in_face((0,1,1), 4)
    color_in_face((1,0,1), 5)
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()

def main():
    to_rotate = False
    pygame.init()
    display = (800,600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    gluPerspective(45,  (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 70.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

    glRotatef(0,0,0,0)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    to_rotate = "left"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    to_rotate = "right"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    to_rotate = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    to_rotate = "down"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    to_rotate = "t-l"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    to_rotate = "t-r"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_z:
                    to_rotate = "b-l"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    to_rotate = "b-r"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    to_rotate = "stop"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    to_rotate = "reload"

        if to_rotate!=None:
            if to_rotate==False:
                glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="left":
                glRotatef(0.5, 0, 1, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="right":
                glRotatef(0.5, 0, -1, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="up":
                glRotatef(0.5, 1, 0, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="down":
                glRotatef(0.5, -1, 0, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="t-l":
                glRotatef(0.5, 1, 1, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="t-r":
                glRotatef(0.5, 1, -1, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="b-l":
                glRotatef(0.5, -1, 1, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="b-r":
                glRotatef(0.5, -1, -1, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="stop":
                glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)
            elif to_rotate=="reload":
                pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
                gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
                glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
                glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    glRotatef(1, 1, 1, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    Cube()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(10)
```

I am using python 3.7 for it,
I have tried using python 3.5 but the result was same
pygame version 1.9.6,
PyOpenGL version 3.1.5

[image: Output]

I guess the issue could be due to Python Versions but I am not Sure<

---

**Edit**:

New code after adding the suggestions from the answer.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

verticies = (
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (1, -1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, -1, 1)
)
edges = (
    (0, 1),
    (0, 5),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 6),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (0, 3),
    (3, 4),
    (4, 7),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 6),
    (4, 5)
)

surfaces = (
    (0, 1, 2, 3),
    (0, 1, 6, 5),
    (0, 3, 4, 5),
    (3, 2, 7, 4),
    (1, 2, 7, 6),
    (4, 5, 6, 7),
)

colors = (
    (1, 0, 0),
    (0, 1, 0),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (0, 0, 0),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (0, 1, 1),
    (1, 0, 0),
    (0, 1, 0),
    (0, 0, 1),
    (0, 0, 0),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (0, 1, 1)
)


def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for surface in surfaces:
        x = 0

        for vertex in surface:
            x += 1
            glColor3fv(colors[x])
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])

    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()


def main():
    to_rotate = False
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 70.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)

    glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    to_rotate = "left"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    to_rotate = "right"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    to_rotate = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    to_rotate = "down"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    to_rotate = "t-l"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    to_rotate = "t-r"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_z:
                    to_rotate = "b-l"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    to_rotate = "b-r"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    to_rotate = "stop"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    to_rotate = "reload"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                    to_rotate = "f"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_v:
                    to_rotate = "v"

        if to_rotate != None:
            if to_rotate == False:
                glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "left":
                glRotatef(0.5, 0, 1, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "right":
                glRotatef(0.5, 0, -1, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "up":
                glRotatef(0.5, 1, 0, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "down":
                glRotatef(0.5, -1, 0, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "t-l":
                glRotatef(0.5, 1, 1, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "t-r":
                glRotatef(0.5, 1, -1, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "b-l":
                glRotatef(0.5, -1, 1, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "b-r":
                glRotatef(0.5, -1, -1, 0)
            elif to_rotate == "stop":
                glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)

            elif to_rotate == "f":
                glRotatef(0.5, 0, 0, 1)
            elif to_rotate == "v":
                glRotatef(0.5, 0, 0, -1)

            elif to_rotate == "reload":
                pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)
                gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
                glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
                glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)


main()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    glRotatef(1, 1, 1, 1)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    Cube()
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.wait(8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem.  The root cause was graphics hardware related.  My pygame 1.9.4+pyOpenGL 3.1.2 used to render correctly. Recently my Intel and Nvidia drivers+control applications were updated and pygame+pyOpenGL was not rendered correctly.

[Bad render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdOSg.png)

I upgraded to pygame 2.0.1+pyOpenGL 3.1.5, but the problem persisted.

My solution was to change in the Nvidia Control Panel's Global Settings the option

- Preferred graphics processor: "Auto-select"
  to
- Preferred graphics processor: "High performance NVIDIA processor"

as shown in the following screenshots of Nvidia's Control Panel:

[Nvidia Control Panel with Preferred graphics processor set to "Auto-select"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvVfj.png)

[Nvidia Control Panel with Preferred graphics processor set to "High performance NVIDIA processor"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIbeI.png)

with this change in the graphics hardware settings, pygame+pyOpenGL were rendered correctly once again producing the right shading of the 3D surfaces as in the following image.

[Good render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3cre.png)

In my case, my laptop (Dell Precision 7530) has an integrated graphics card (Intel UHD 630) and a high performance graphics card (Nvidia Quadro P2000).  With the original setting from factory never experienced this problem (my laptop is two years old).  Apparently after some driver/control panel update the configuration changed.

There is another "dirty" fix to the rendering problem, which I comment in case might be useful under other situations.  This fix is to turn off double buffering and do it manually, i.e.:

At initialization issue the command:

```
pygame.display.set_mode(display, OPENGL)   # <--- Note "DOUBLEBUF|" was removed

# [... GL drawing commands ...]
```

At the end after all GL drawing commands force their execution:

```
glFlush()               # <--- Force the execution of GL commands
pygame.display.flip()   #      before pygame.display.flip()

# [...  rest of the code   ...]
```

Probably this solution is useful when the available graphic hardware is not able to do double buffering.

Answer (score 1):

You missed to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) and if you want to use the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test)t, you need to ensure that the default frame buffer has a depth buffer. Set the depth buffer size attribute (`GL_DEPTH_SIZE`) with [`pygame.display.gl_set_attribute`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) (Try a size of 24, if that doesn't work then switch to 16):

```py
def main():
    to_rotate = False
    pygame.init()
    display = (800,600)

    pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24) # <--- set depth buffer size

    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) # <--- enable depth test
    
    gluPerspective(45,  (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 70.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

    glRotatef(0,0,0,0)
    while True:
        # [...]
```

The default depth test function is `GL_LESS`. If the depth test fails, a fragment is discarded. Hence if a fragment is drawn in a location where another fragment was previously drawn that was closer to the camera, the new fragment will be discarded.

---

All the matrix operations like `glRotate`, `glTranslate`, `gluPerspective`, etc. specify a new matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix.

If you want to reset the view, then you have to load the [Identity Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) before by [`glLoadIdentity`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glLoadIdentity.html):

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    while True:
        # [...]

            
        elif to_rotate=="reload":

            glLoadIdentity()  # <--- load identity matrix

            gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)
```

Legacy OpenGL provides different current matrices (see [`glMatrixMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMatrixMode.xml)). The projection matrix should be set to the current projection matrix (`GL_PROJECTION`) and the model view matrix to the current model view matrix (`GL_MODELVIEW`):

```py
def main():
    # [...]
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45,  (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 70.0)
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
verticies = (
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (1, -1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (1, -1, 1)
)
edges=(
    (0,1),
    (0,5),
    (1,2),
    (1,6),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (0,3),
    (3,4),
    (4,7),
    (6,7),
    (5,6),
    (4,5)
)

surfaces = (
    (0,1,2,3),
    (0,1,6,5),
    (0,3,4,5),
    (3,2,7,4),
    (1,2,7,6),
    (4,5,6,7),
)

colors= ()
def color_in_face(color, face_index):
    for vertex in surfaces[face_index]:
        glColor3fv(color)
        glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    color_in_face((1,0,0), 0)
    color_in_face((0,1,0), 1)
    color_in_face((0,0,1), 2)
    color_in_face((1,1,0), 3)
    color_in_face((0,1,1), 4)
    color_in_face((1,0,1), 5)
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()

def main():
    to_rotate = False
    pygame.init()
    display = (800,600)
    pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    gluPerspective(45,  (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 70.0)
    
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)
    
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    to_rotate = "left"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    to_rotate = "right"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    to_rotate = "up"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    to_rotate = "down"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    to_rotate = "t-l"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    to_rotate = "t-r"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_z:
                    to_rotate = "b-l"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_x:
                    to_rotate = "b-r"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    to_rotate = "stop"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    to_rotate = "reload"

        if to_rotate=="left":
            glRotatef(0.5, 0, 1, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="right":
            glRotatef(0.5, 0, -1, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="up":
            glRotatef(0.5, 1, 0, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="down":
            glRotatef(0.5, -1, 0, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="t-l":
            glRotatef(0.5, 1, 1, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="t-r":
            glRotatef(0.5, 1, -1, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="b-l":
            glRotatef(0.5, -1, 1, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="b-r":
            glRotatef(0.5, -1, -1, 0)
        elif to_rotate=="reload":
            glLoadIdentity()
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```

Comment: I tried but there was no improvent
I added 
`glEnable(GL_EQUAL)` but it remained the same i added `glLoadIdentity()` but still the result remained the same
I even Copied the complete Code but still i got no different result

Also is my OpenGl Legacy or New one? i dont Know about it Much

Comment: @Lakshya Most likely your window (default framebuffer) doesn't have a depth buffer. Set the size of the depth buffer: `pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24)` or `pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16)`. I've extended the answer.

Comment: that didnt helped

What can i do now ? 
btw, i have edited the code in the Question a Bit

Comment: I added but still no result. 

you may copy my code and do some tweaks and send me the code here
then i would Understand it Completely what was my error

Comment: yes i have Checked it is Upto Date.
what version of Python, pygame and openGL are you running and on which OS?

Comment: @Lakshya This is not related to the OS. It is related to your hardware and graphics driver.

Comment: Still Not Working correctly I guess there might be a issue in my Graphics Card thanks for helping me out i will run it on some other Device and see the result

Comment: yes @Rabbid76
My Graphics card was not working I ran the code on some other PC and it worked just absolutely fine